# Reference for CTL* logic

Tags: reference-request, lo.logic, temporal-logic

I need a reference for CTL* logic (preferably easy to understand).

I have gathered some disperse information regarding temporal and CTL logic but I need a more orderly coverage. A chapter of the multi-agent systems book I read depends on this subject and I am stuck.

Comment: How about the book ["Model Checking"](http://mitpress.mit.edu/books/model-checking) by EM Clarke et al?

Comment: Yes, that's a good bock. Very much appreciated.

Comment: There is also http://is.ifmo.ru/books/_principles_of_model_checking.pdf
and the new "Handbook of Model Checking".

Answer (score 1):

See Venema, Yde. Temporal Logic. The blackwell guide to Philosophical Logic.

Comment: Hey, it seems like your post has been flagged as "low quality".

May I kindly suggest that you expand on your answer, e.g. by giving reasons this book is suitable for the purposes stated in the question, the recommended audience (beginner? graduate? etc.) as to improve it?

Comment: He is pointing to http://www.blackwellreference.com/public/tocnode?id=g9780631206934_chunk_g978063120693413 which is a very good reference for temporal logic. The person who downvoted should be blamed.